# Web Performance Error (Request failed error)

Tags: visual-studio-2010, connection, performance-testing

While running web performance test I get an error "Request failed: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host" only for 1 request,

It takes around 132 sec for processing and after that it gives this error.When I run the same steps via browser page gets loaded without any error......

Being 1 of the important step in web performance I cant ignore this request....

Any suggestion how to solve this

Comment: What does the log of the webserver say? Of the server itself? Any authentication on that page? client-side certificates needed? If you put fiddler in place, is the request from your browser the same as from your performancetest? Is the webapplication in a particular state that you din't reach yet form hand testing?

Comment: I have cross verified the request from fiddler and found that it is same, The same request doesnt fail if I do it via browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best guess is you have missed a piece of dynamic data in the request (or the immediate prior request) in question which needs to be handled.   What you missed, assuming it is early in the business process flow, will likely fall into one of the following categories:

- Session
- State
- Security
- Time

If it was a little later in the business process then you would likely have to contend with business process data as a dynamic element as well.

Comment: I have compared my webperformance recording with recording done in Fiddler and found that request are same.

Comment: Clear your cache and record two sessions.  It need not be the rquest which threw the error, for unless you are checking for expected results the likelihood is actually quite high that your business process came off the tracks a couple of calls prior