# Existing connection forcibly closed at Manage Extensions, VS 2019

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions

Just installed vs2019 community on a fresh laptop.

Going to install some extensions and I see this

[image]

If I refresh several times, there is a change that I may see the extensions, but in the next refresh or when going to next page of extensions, I see the same thing.

No clue whatsoever on what is happening, why, and how to solve it.

**UPDATE**

I tried to install an extension from the [marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com) site. It failed

[image]

I opened the logs and again, same error:

```
14/05/2021 17:52:17 - One or more errors occurred.
14/05/2021 17:52:17 -    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.get_Result()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.VSGalleryRepository.GetExtensions[T](List`1 extensionIds, Int32 lcid, Boolean forAutoupdate)
   at VSIXInstaller.ExtensionPackService.GetExtensionByVsixId(List`1 vsixIds, String extensionPackParentName, IExtensionEngine extensionEngine, List`1 extensionsToInstall, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
14/05/2021 17:52:17 - END: Gathering extension pack information
14/05/2021 17:52:17 - END: Processing extension pack
14/05/2021 17:52:17 - System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. ---> System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send. ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndReceive(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.EndRead(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Telemetry.WindowsErrorReporting.WatsonReport.GetClrWatsonExceptionInfo(Exception exceptionObject)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.TlsStream.EndWrite(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.PooledStream.EndWrite(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.ConnectStream.WriteHeadersCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetRequestStream(IAsyncResult asyncResult, TransportContext& context)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.GetRequestStreamCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.VSGalleryRepositoryHelper.<PostAndGetResponseAsync>d__9`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.VSGalleryRepository.<>c__DisplayClass14_0`1.<<GetExtensionsOrCategoriesAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.VSGalleryRepository.<GetExtensionsOrCategoriesAsync>d__14`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.VSGalleryRepository.<GetExtensionsAsync>d__13`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.VSGalleryRepository.<>c__DisplayClass12_0`1.<<GetExtensions>b__1>d.MoveNext()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.get_Result()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.VSGalleryRepository.GetExtensions[T](List`1 extensionIds, Int32 lcid, Boolean forAutoupdate)
   at VSIXInstaller.ExtensionPackService.GetExtensionByVsixId(List`1 vsixIds, String extensionPackParentName, IExtensionEngine extensionEngine, List`1 extensionsToInstall, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at VSIXInstaller.ExtensionPackService.AcquireExtensionPack(IList`1 extensionsPath, IStateData stateData, Boolean isRepairSupported)
   at VSIXInstaller.ExtensionPackService.ExpandExtensionPackToInstall(IStateData stateData, Boolean isRepairSupported)
   at VSIXInstaller.App.Initialize(Boolean isRepairSupported)
   at VSIXInstaller.App.Initialize()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
---> (Inner Exception #0) System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. ---> System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send. ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndReceive(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.EndRead(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Telemetry.WindowsErrorReporting.WatsonReport.GetClrWatsonExceptionInfo(Exception exceptionObject)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.TlsStream.EndWrite(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.PooledStream.EndWrite(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.ConnectStream.WriteHeadersCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetRequestStream(IAsyncResult asyncResult, TransportContext& context)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.GetRequestStreamCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.VSGalleryRepositoryHelper.<PostAndGetResponseAsync>d__9`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.VSGalleryRepository.<>c__DisplayClass14_0`1.<<GetExtensionsOrCategoriesAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.VSGalleryRepository.<GetExtensionsOrCategoriesAsync>d__14`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.VSGalleryRepository.<GetExtensionsAsync>d__13`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.VSGalleryRepository.<>c__DisplayClass12_0`1.<<GetExtensions>b__1>d.MoveNext()<---
```

**UPDATE 2**

Seems that even connection to the marketplace from browser is a problem

[image]

**UPDATE 3**
Having used Fiddler to inspect the problem further I get an HTTPS handshake failed.

**UPDATE 4**
While connecting to the internet through another WIFI network, the problem disappeared. More specifically I turned my mobile to a wifi hotspot and connected through the mobile. No more connection errors to visual studio marketplace...

**UPDATE 5 - SOLUTION**
After I realized that the problem appeared in certain wifi networks and not always, I suspected that something wrong is going on with my wifi adapter settings. I removed ipv6 from my adapter settings and everything worked like a charm.

Comment: Can you access this site: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/, then download extensions?

Comment: I can probably download extension from there but I would like things to work and not try to find workarounds

Comment: @DylanZhu-MSFT tried to install web essentials 2019 from the marketplace site. It failed. I opened the logs and there was the same exception "An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host"

Comment: @DylanZhu-MSFT i get a https handshake failure when connecting to marketplace. I have no clue on why. I use fiddler to capture traffic.

Comment: You can have a try to follow this similar thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57247988/14324452

Comment: @DylanZhu-MSFT I don't use any proxy

Comment: According to update information, your environment cannot access visual studio extension server. So I suggest you try to configure the proxy to access the server.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

After reading a lot of different solutions to that problem, most of which were about configuration of proxy settings, I finally found what was causing the problem in my case.

None of the solutions I found worked. The only one close enough was a post about disabling ipv6 from visual studio's config file. Which I did but it seems the change was ignored. So I though ipv6 wouldn't be the root cause in my case and changed direction, but in vain.

When, at some point, I needed to connect to a different Wi-Fi network, I realized the problem was gone. Only in certain wi-fi I had this problem, and only on my laptop. Not any other of my devices. So I suspected there must be some combination of my laptop's Wi-Fi adapter settings and the Wi-Fi network that causes the problem.

Fiddling with the settings of my Wi-Fi network adapter, I found what I needed to do. **I had to disable ipv6 from my Wi-Fi adapter settings**.

And problem is gone.

[image]

In Windows 10 Control Panel in a section “Network and Sharing Centre” click "Change Adapter Settings" and open properties (right mouse click) of  the adapter, that you are using(it may be Ethernet or Wi-Fi).

Comment: Just has this problem on VS 2022 and this was the solution in my case as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Same problem for me but with Ethernet connection, and connection to Visual Studio Marketplace worked after unticking IPv6.
Hopefully MSFT fixes this issue; IPv6 is the future.
Makes no sense that the Marketplace server would not complete a TCP handshake simply because the client can use both IPv4 and IPv6.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31281091)

Answer (score 0):

Based on your **update 3** it seems that your TLS version is the root cause. Here is link to the MSDN Issue asking the same issue [Link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/8fd4d9f8-2276-4c4a-978c-7cf462f30b5f/request-failed-an-existing-connection-was-forcibly-closed-by-the-remote-host?forum=vstest)

**Potential Fixes**

1. Update and enable TLS 1.1 / 1.2 on your New laptop (**Usually done by installing the MS patches for the OS your using**)
2. Check the proxy setting in your project solution which is set by default by your VS.

   **#Ref** [MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/20f595d6-9d81-4782-a488-099e4f504d45/request-failed-existing-connection-closed-unable-to-read-data-from-transport-connection?forum=vstswebtest), [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14020297/web-performance-error-request-failed-error), [How to configure proxy setting in vs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56247226/how-to-configure-proxy-in-visual-studio-2019)

Comment: TLS is already 1.2. No problem there.

Interestingly enough, when I turned my 4G phone into a wireless hotspot and connected to internet through the phone's WIFI, the problem dissapeared. There must be a problem with the wifi of my router.

Comment: Yes it seems that why or it could be either firwall or av on your new machine.  Maybe first try while disabling firewall and av

Comment: Well, finally, the problem was ipv6. I had to disable ipv6 from my wireless connection and everything worked properly. I was aware that ipv6 might be a problem so, initially, I disabled it from visual studio's config file. But it seemed that the setting was ignored (or I edited the wrong config file). Then when I connected to another wifi network I saw the problem disappeared. So I suspected that something is going on with my wireless connection to my home network. I fiddled with the settings and disabling ipv6 did the trick for me.

Comment: Well atleast you found a solution.